# Worklight: Which APNS library worklight is using

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to know which APNS library has been used in Worklight? and can we extend it ? or customize it as per our own needs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the way Worklight interfaces against APNS is by using [notnoop](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns), but this is a server-side library, pre-compiled and packaged. You cannot extend it. This library cannot be replaced, either.

On the client-side, we do not document nor provide support for any modifications one may do.
I know this [has been done to some extent for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831893/ibm-worklight-push-notification-and-badge) ([here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050659/ibm-worklight-extend-server-side-java-code/16831357#16831357)), but do not know about iOS - since Apple keeps things close-knit, one is not able to extend the functionality...

Comment: Great, BTW, If i use my own implementation of notnoop on server side, and send messages directly using it rather than adapters. Do you think is it fine? the reason is same I am facing message size limit. However I can keep the adapters for user's subscriptions or UnSubscriptions. What you suggest? thanks